# HTML.TextAreaFor - removing html tags for display only

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC application I have to use @HTML.TextAreaFor to display some text from a database, the trouble is sometimes that text may have HTML tags within it and I can't see a way to remove those for display only.

Is it possible to do this in the view (maybe with CSS?) without having to strip the tags in the controller first?

EDIT

The data coming from the controller contains html tags which I do not want to remove, I just don't want to display them

Normally I would use @HTML.Raw but it has to work in a @HTML.TextAreaFor control.

Comment: Do you want to display or remove `html`? It is not obvious, could you explain the problem a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decode `Html` returned from the `Controller` you can use the following `JavaScript` method:

This method decodes "Chris' corner" to "Chris' corner".

```
var decodeEntities = (function () {
// this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
var element = document.createElement('div');

function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
    if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
        // strip script/html tags
        str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
        str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
        element.innerHTML = str;
        str = element.textContent;
        element.textContent = '';
    }
    return str;
}
return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a razor code in your view.

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content))
```

if I set Model.Content to this string `"<strong>This is me</strong><button>click</button>"`, the code above will render it like HTML code and will have a strong text next to a button as an output like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's some nice rich text editors libraries like [CK Editor](https://ckeditor.com/), [Quill](https://quilljs.com/), or [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) that can display HTML while still maintaining the editor capabilities of being a text editor. All of these libraries have capabilities of being *read-only* as well if that's necessary.

Example from Quill -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by changing TextAreaFor toTextBoxFor and setting a formatted value.

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.MyItem,  new { @class = "form-control", @required = "true", Value = Regex.Replace(Model.MyItem, "<.*?>", String.Empty) })